# How to change Totem buffer size?

Tags: configuration, totem

I've seen some suggestions by using `gconf-editor` but it doesn't seem to work anymore. The option may have been removed ([see](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2010-April/msg01781.html)).

Is there another way to increase Totem buffer size so when I see a video trough LAN it doesn't lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is in gsettings though atm can't check 11.10, ex. here on  12.04 shows default of 2.0 sec.'s, then setting to 3.0

```
~$ gsettings get org.gnome.totem network-buffer-threshold
2.0
~$ gsettings set org.gnome.totem network-buffer-threshold 3.0
```

Or take a look in `dconf-editor` > org.gnome.totem & see if there, (otherwise will be there in 12.04

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes this configuration is here in 11.10 and I think you answered the question. But Totem doesn't seems to "know" that the file comes from LAN when I open a file from a shared samba mounted in nautilus. Do you know how to tell Totem? Or another way to open the video? Again thank you so much!

Comment: never had a 'samba', (windows share? I guess

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter if it is samba (`smb://192.168.0.100`) or ftp (`ftp://192.168.0.100`) mounted with Nautilus. Totem treats the videos as if they were local.

Comment: I think it is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/108623

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/400555/72807), the manual says that all configuration are done graphically, thereafter it can't be changed unless by compiling from source.

If someone else need a larger buffer size, I suggest to use [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) which has very good [documentation](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html).

To change the buffer of mplayer size just add

```
cache=8192
cache-min=4
```

to the file `~/.mplayer/config`.

Which means that you will have a buffer of 8MB, and that playback begins when 4% of the 8MB (~330kB) are already buffered.

Reference: [1](http://martin.ankerl.com/2006/06/10/pimp-my-mplayer/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add gconf-editor by simpy typing the following in a terminal prompt

```
#sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

The gconf keys are stored in your home directory.

> cd ~/.gconf

So to take a quick look at totems gconf values, run the following:

> cat /home/username/.gconf/apps/totem/%gconf.xml

I think from here, you can pick up the directions you [linked](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2010-April/msg01781.html) above and modify / add the correct key you need.

Comment: Thank you for answering but, as I said, manually adding an entry `/apps/totem/buffer-size` in `gconf-editor` doesn't work anymore.